# Problems with SharePoint EventReceiver ItemUpdating on Custom List Definition

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, eventreceiver

I have a problem with my CustomListDefinition and a CustomEventReceiver.

The ListDefinition works fine. I can create Lists out of it and everything looks as it should. My EventReceiver acts on the following four events: ItemAdding, ItemAdded, ItemUpdating and ItemUpdated.

While adding/updating ListItems via WebInterface, everythings works without any errors. When I try to create or edit a ListItem via C# (or PowerShell), I get the following error:

> "Unknown Status Module: 33 Message: 134"

even when the code is doing really **nothing**! I reproduced the problem with a new and empty EventReceiver, that is attached to the ItemUpdating event of my custom ListDefinition.

This problem occurs only on the **ItemUpdating** event. When I deploy my solution without this event, everything is going on well. Deploying an EventReceiver to standard list (e.g. Task ListDefinition) there is no problem like above, too.

So my conclusion is, there must be an error in my ListDefinition.

Can someone help me finding the error?

**My Elements.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <!-- Do not change the value of the Name attribute below. If it does not match the folder name of the List Definition project item, an error will occur when the project is run. -->
    <ListTemplate
        Name="MyProject.ListDefinition.Booking"
        Type="10001"
        BaseType="0"
        OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
        SecurityBits="11"
        AllowDeletion="TRUE"
        DisallowContentTypes="FALSE"
        Sequence="410"
        DisplayName="Anmeldung"
        Description="Anmeldeliste für ein Fest"
        Image="/_layouts/images/itgen.png"/>
</Elements>
```

**My Schema.xml (ContentType and Field Definitions defined as in the code below)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="Fest Anmeldung" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/Fest-MyProject.ListDefinition.Booking" BaseType="0" EnableContentTypes="TRUE" DisableAttachments="TRUE" EnableMinorVersions="FALSE" ModeratedList="FALSE" PrivateList="FALSE" VersioningEnabled="FALSE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentType ID="0x0100d05f16219b3543eb81f2b7707d50a4d3" Name="externer Teilnehmer" Group="MyProject.Fest" Description="externer Teilnehmer am Fest" Inherits="TRUE" Version="0">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" DisplayName="Titel" Required="FALSE" />
          <FieldRef ID="{F168D67A-8BE4-42ED-B3D6-D04C3CE487F9}" Name="MyProjectFestFirstName" />
          <FieldRef ID="{EA8D4CAA-A219-43ED-8796-345E387BD4C6}" Name="MyProjectFestLastName" />
          <FieldRef ID="{A29AE60F-BCCA-47B5-A498-17B4E7FD4297}" Name="MyProjectFestParticipates" />
          <FieldRef ID="{08885975-334B-4BB6-B7A7-052610C2F885}" Name="MyProjectFestPartner" />
          <FieldRef ID="{5E480332-98F6-4328-955E-037F6F1C66DE}" Name="MyProjectFestChildrenCount0To3" />
          <FieldRef ID="{0BD4A5E1-171F-41AA-9628-979694549807}" Name="MyProjectFestChildrenCount4To8" />
          <FieldRef ID="{90F8CEE7-289B-499B-AA6E-3BE92568948D}" Name="MyProjectFestChildrenCount9To15" />
          <FieldRef ID="{9EB35619-530A-4149-9889-1CEDB7CF3C9F}" Name="MyProjectFestChildrenCount16" />
          <FieldRef ID="{6B63D7A4-4FCC-4C16-979A-BB640FAADA61}" Name="MyProjectFestArrivalDate" />
          <FieldRef ID="{B390E3B7-76C8-4E03-A54E-FD3106689FFE}" Name="MyProjectFestAccommodations" />
          <FieldRef ID="{DEE42C9A-238E-4E93-971B-6BFE3BE5B53B}" Name="MyProjectFestFood" />
          <FieldRef ID="{A6056EA2-E4B8-4555-B5FF-0CDD8FD415FC}" Name="MyProjectFestParticipantCount" />
          <FieldRef ID="{C204C403-CDD5-4A09-AF58-A21D7AEBF985}" Name="MyProjectFestBranch" />
          <FieldRef ID="{EF54ACED-E2BE-4EB7-BF39-1D2A46202DFC}" Name="MyProjectFestDescription" />
        </FieldRefs>
      </ContentType>
      <ContentType ID="0x0100e498ffd129d6485fbe5174d501bbf362" Name="interner Teilnehmer" Group="MyProject.Fest" Description="interner Teilnehmer am Fest" Inherits="TRUE" Version="0">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" DisplayName="Titel" Required="FALSE" />
          <FieldRef ID="{F168D67A-8BE4-42ED-B3D6-D04C3CE487F9}" Name="MyProjectFestFirstName" />
          <FieldRef ID="{EA8D4CAA-A219-43ED-8796-345E387BD4C6}" Name="MyProjectFestLastName" />
          <FieldRef ID="{A29AE60F-BCCA-47B5-A498-17B4E7FD4297}" Name="MyProjectFestParticipates" />
          <FieldRef ID="{08885975-334B-4BB6-B7A7-052610C2F885}" Name="MyProjectFestPartner" />
          <FieldRef ID="{5E480332-98F6-4328-955E-037F6F1C66DE}" Name="MyProjectFestChildrenCount0To3" />
          <FieldRef ID="{0BD4A5E1-171F-41AA-9628-979694549807}" Name="MyProjectFestChildrenCount4To8" />
          <FieldRef ID="{90F8CEE7-289B-499B-AA6E-3BE92568948D}" Name="MyProjectFestChildrenCount9To15" />
          <FieldRef ID="{9EB35619-530A-4149-9889-1CEDB7CF3C9F}" Name="MyProjectFestChildrenCount16" />
          <FieldRef ID="{6B63D7A4-4FCC-4C16-979A-BB640FAADA61}" Name="MyProjectFestArrivalDate" />
          <FieldRef ID="{B390E3B7-76C8-4E03-A54E-FD3106689FFE}" Name="MyProjectFestAccommodations" />
          <FieldRef ID="{DEE42C9A-238E-4E93-971B-6BFE3BE5B53B}" Name="MyProjectFestFood" />
          <FieldRef ID="{A6056EA2-E4B8-4555-B5FF-0CDD8FD415FC}" Name="MyProjectFestParticipantCount" />
          <FieldRef ID="{C204C403-CDD5-4A09-AF58-A21D7AEBF985}" Name="MyProjectFestBranch" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE" />
          <FieldRef ID="{3BAC8D07-9B0D-4D8A-8899-8A398E94A5DC}" Name="MyProjectFestSystemMitaId" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE"  />
          <FieldRef ID="{026BDDB3-C776-4873-A82D-1A87BA4FE4B8}" Name="MyProjectFestSystemAccount" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE"  />
          <FieldRef ID="{99EB27C2-156A-42AD-AC42-8BE91AE1CEC7}" Name="MyProjectFestActivityStatus" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE"  />
        </FieldRefs>
      </ContentType>
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
      <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" Type="Text" DisplayName="Titel" Required="FALSE" />

      <Field
   ID="{F168D67A-8BE4-42ED-B3D6-D04C3CE487F9}"
   Name="MyProjectFestFirstName"
   DisplayName="Vorname"
   Type="Text"
   Required="TRUE"
   Sealed="TRUE"
   AllowDeletion="FALSE"
   Group="MyProjectFest"
   Filterable="TRUE"
   Sortable="TRUE" />

      <Field
        ID="{EA8D4CAA-A219-43ED-8796-345E387BD4C6}"
        Name="MyProjectFestLastName"
        DisplayName="Nachname"
        Type="Text"
        Required="TRUE"
        Sealed="TRUE"
        AllowDeletion="FALSE"
        Group="MyProjectFest"
        Filterable="TRUE"
        Sortable="TRUE" />

      <Field
        ID="{A29AE60F-BCCA-47B5-A498-17B4E7FD4297}"
        Name="MyProjectFestParticipates"
        DisplayName="Teilnahme am Fest"
        Type="Boolean"
        Required="FALSE"
        Sealed="TRUE"
        AllowDeletion="FALSE"
        Description="Falls nein, müssen die weiteren Felder nicht ausgefüllt werden!"
        Group="MyProjectFest"
        Filterable="TRUE"
        Sortable="TRUE"  />

      <Field
        ID="{08885975-334B-4BB6-B7A7-052610C2F885}"
        Name="MyProjectFestPartner"
        DisplayName="Teilnahme Partner"
        Type="Boolean"
        Required="FALSE"
        Sealed="TRUE"
        AllowDeletion="FALSE"
        Group="MyProjectFest"
        Filterable="TRUE"
        Sortable="TRUE"  />

      <Field
        ID="{5E480332-98F6-4328-955E-037F6F1C66DE}"
        Name="MyProjectFestChildrenCount0To3"
        DisplayName="Anzahl Kinder (0-3)"
        Type="Number"
        Decimals="0"
        Min="0"
        Max="10"
        Required="FALSE"
        Sealed="TRUE"
        AllowDeletion="FALSE"
        Group="MyProjectFest"
        Filterable="TRUE"
        Sortable="TRUE"  />

      <Field
        ID="{0BD4A5E1-171F-41AA-9628-979694549807}"
        Name="MyProjectFestChildrenCount4To8"
        DisplayName="Anzahl Kinder (4-8)"
        Type="Number"
        Decimals="0"
        Min="0"
        Max="10"
        Required="FALSE"
        Sealed="TRUE"
        AllowDeletion="FALSE"
        Group="MyProjectFest"
        Filterable="TRUE"
        Sortable="TRUE"  />

      <Field
        ID="{90F8CEE7-289B-499B-AA6E-3BE92568948D}"
        Name="MyProjectFestChildrenCount9To15"
        DisplayName="Anzahl Kinder (9-15)"
        Type="Number"
        Decimals="0"
        Min="0"
        Max="10"
        Required="FALSE"
        Sealed="TRUE"
        AllowDeletion="FALSE"
        Group="MyProjectFest"
        Filterable="TRUE"
        Sortable="TRUE"  />

      <Field
        ID="{9EB35619-530A-4149-9889-1CEDB7CF3C9F}"
        Name="MyProjectFestChildrenCount16"
        DisplayName="Anzahl Kinder (16+)"
        Type="Number"
        Decimals="0"
        Min="0"
        Max="10"
        Required="FALSE"
        Sealed="TRUE"
        AllowDeletion="FALSE"
        Group="MyProjectFest"
        Filterable="TRUE"
        Sortable="TRUE"  />

      <Field
        ID="{6B63D7A4-4FCC-4C16-979A-BB640FAADA61}"
        Name="MyProjectFestArrivalDate"
        DisplayName="Anreise-Datum"
        Type="DateTime"
        Format="DateOnly"
        Required="FALSE"
        Sealed="TRUE"
        AllowDeletion="FALSE"
        Group="MyProjectFest"
        Filterable="TRUE"
        Sortable="TRUE"  />

      <Field
        ID="{B390E3B7-76C8-4E03-A54E-FD3106689FFE}"
        Name="MyProjectFestAccommodations"
        DisplayName="Anzahl Übernachtungen"
        Type="Number"
        Decimals="0"
        Min="0"
        Max="10"
        Required="FALSE"
        Sealed="TRUE"
        AllowDeletion="FALSE"
        Group="MyProjectFest"
        Filterable="TRUE"
        Sortable="TRUE"  />

      <Field
        ID="{DEE42C9A-238E-4E93-971B-6BFE3BE5B53B}"
        Name="MyProjectFestFood"
        DisplayName="mitgebrachte Speise"
        Type="Text"
        Required="FALSE"
        Sealed="TRUE"
        AllowDeletion="FALSE"
        Group="MyProjectFest"
        Filterable="TRUE"
        Sortable="TRUE"  />

      <Field ID="{3bac8d07-9b0d-4d8a-8899-8a398e94a5dc}" Name="MyProjectFestSystemMitaId" DisplayName="SYSTEM_MITA_ID" Type="Number" Decimals="0" Required="FALSE" Sealed="TRUE" AllowDeletion="FALSE" Group="MyProjectFest" />
      <Field ID="{026bddb3-c776-4873-a82d-1a87ba4fe4b8}" Name="MyProjectFestSystemAccount" DisplayName="Account-Name" Type="Text" MaxLength="5" Required="FALSE" Sealed="TRUE" AllowDeletion="FALSE" Group="MyProjectFest" />
      <Field ID="{99eb27c2-156a-42ad-ac42-8be91ae1cec7}" Name="MyProjectFestActivityStatus" DisplayName="Status" Type="Text" MaxLength="10" Required="FALSE" Sealed="TRUE" AllowDeletion="FALSE" Group="MyProjectFest" />

      <Field ID="{ef54aced-e2be-4eb7-bf39-1d2a46202dfc}" Name="MyProjectFestDescription" DisplayName="Beschreibung" Type="Note" NumLines="3" Required="FALSE" Sealed="TRUE" AllowDeletion="FALSE" Group="MyProjectFest" Filterable="TRUE" Sortable="TRUE" />
      <Field ID="{c204c403-cdd5-4a09-af58-a21d7aebf985}" Name="MyProjectFestBranch" DisplayName="Niederlassung" Type="Choice" Format="Dropdown" BaseType="Text" Required="FALSE" Sealed="FALSE" AllowDeletion="FALSE" Group="MyProjectFest" Filterable="TRUE" Sortable="TRUE">
        <CHOICES>
          <CHOICE>B</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>E</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>HH</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>K</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>M</CHOICE>
        </CHOICES>
        <Default>K</Default>
      </Field>

      <Field
        ID="{A6056EA2-E4B8-4555-B5FF-0CDD8FD415FC}"
        Name="MyProjectFestParticipantCount"
        DisplayName="Teilnehmeranzahl"
        Type="Calculated"
        ResultType="Number"
        ReadOnly="FALSE"
        Hidden="FALSE"
        Decimals="0"
        Group="MyProjectFest">
        <Formula>=IF([MyProjectFestParticipates]=TRUE,1+IF([MyProjectFestPartner]=TRUE,1,0)+[MyProjectFestChildrenCount0To3]+[MyProjectFestChildrenCount4To8]+[MyProjectFestChildrenCount9To15]+[MyProjectFestChildrenCount16],0)</Formula>
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef Name="MyProjectFestParticipates" />
          <FieldRef Name="MyProjectFestPartner" />
          <FieldRef Name="MyProjectFestChildrenCount0To3" />
          <FieldRef Name="MyProjectFestChildrenCount4To8" />
          <FieldRef Name="MyProjectFestChildrenCount9To15" />
          <FieldRef Name="MyProjectFestChildrenCount16" />
        </FieldRefs>
      </Field>
    </Fields>
    <Views>
      <View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="MyProjectFestFirstName" />
          <FieldRef Name="MyProjectFestLastName" />
          <FieldRef Name="MyProjectFestParticipates" />
          <FieldRef Name="MyProjectFestParticipantCount" />
        </ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE">
            </FieldRef>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_ONET_HOME)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="Attachments">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="MyProjectFestFirstName" />
          <FieldRef Name="MyProjectFestLastName" />
          <FieldRef Name="MyProjectFestParticipates" />
          <FieldRef Name="MyProjectFestParticipantCount" />
        </ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="ID">
            </FieldRef>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View>
    </Views>
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

The code is a little bit anonymized and could contain some typing errors because of that. ;)

Hope you can help me find my problem.

Edit:
I found out, that this error is occurring in the event log:

> Error loading and running event receiver
>   MyProject.BookingItemEventReceiver in OC.Sommerfest, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=asdasdasd. Additional information is
>   below.

The Event ID is 6875.

Comment: Have you check your Event receiver work perfectly? means attach your Debug Point? I think problem with Event Receiver Event Firing.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your suggestion. I got an EventReceiver attached to my ListDefinition and it worked. I created a new sandbox solution and added an EventReceiver firing on my ListDefinition on ItemUpdating. so now i'm convinced that the problem is not my ListDefinition but my EventReceiver or assembly/solution... i will try on!

Answer (score 0):

try to updated listitem code during [`EventFiringEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceiverbase.eventfiringenabled.aspx) with set false.

something like :

```
   this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
    //item updated logic
   this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
```

Comment: it is happening even when there is no code inside the itemupdating function.

Comment: It seems, that I have the problems because of sandbox solution. Any further helps? Isn't it possible to deploy eventreceivers in sandbox solutions?

Comment: yes.its possible to deploy eventreceivers in SB.Plz read this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798382.aspx                                                        Also might be helpful this : http://online.appdev.com/edge/blogs/doug_ware/archive/2011/08/05/tip-debugging-feature-event-receivers-in-sharepoint-sandbox-solutions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I'm currently trying to solve. 
In my case, use a custom list created by Site Contents Menu.

1. But I checked the error appears when inside a catch an unhandled exception is thrown.
2. Another reason could be the length of the string that you retorned in the errormessage is to long.

If I find a new solution I share.

regards...